# React router path as an array

Tags: react-router

I have a code like this :

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={component1} />
    <Route path="/somewhere/:something" component={component2} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I tried this, because in the end, I want to match several paths with the same component / result :

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path={["/somewhere/:something","/somewhere2/:something"]} component={component2} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

and the path is matched, but my parameter (:something) isnt passed to it. Any idea why ? react-router's docs [tells me](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string-string) :

> Any valid URL path or array of paths that path-to-regexp@^1.7.0 understands.

Comment: in fact, I noticed that error : Failed prop type: Invalid prop `path` of type `array` supplied to `Route`, expected `string`. which is inconsistent with the docs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feature was only recently [added to React-Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/5889). You need to upgrade your react-router installation to be able to match the documentation and use the feature.